# Listing record specific nested data from a single store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a store, model, scriptTagProxy and custom Reader that consumes some json(p). The json describes a collection of objects. Each parent object hasMany child objects.

Is it possible to use an Ext.List to list all the children for a parent? - In my research it seems that you have to point a list at a store.

I would like alternatives to a nestedList.

Answer (score 0):

Use `store.filter('parentID', specificParentId);` on the store that is binded to the list.

To change the items on the list to another parent clear the current filter first with `store.clearFilter(false);`

Comment: Perhaps there is another step? filtering the store just shows 1 item (the parent item) - I want to show all the children items inside this in the list

Comment: All the children items must have some common property with same value. If that's not the case I don't think there is another way without using a different store.
Except if you can fetch only the children via specific URL then you can use the same store and change the proxy for each parent.

Comment: I think you assumed the parent child relationships where kept across two different stores via a common key. There is only 1 store.